# Bulk PATCH in python eve

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

Can I perform a PATCH request to collection?

Like `UPDATE table SET foo=bar WHERE some>10` in SQL.

Comment: Technically it breaks REST paradigm. You should update documents, not collections. So if you need it, you should just write your own resource in which you update or do whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

No that is not supported, and probably should not (see Andrey Shipilov comment).